# Insert Javascript (jquery) variable in a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I promise having searched a "simple answer to this" (I insist on the word "Simple"), but unfortunatly I cant find any answer (or approachable answer regarding my understanding of JSON/Jquery).
Surely I'm too noob in JSON to create a precise question (and find the right answer...)

Anyway, here my problem.

My JSON file prices.json (example) :

```
{
  "test1" : {
    "sub_test1_1" : 10,
    "sub_test1_2" : 20,
    "sub_test1_3" : 30,
  },
  "test2" : {
    "sub_test2_1" : 40,
    "sub_test2_2" : 50,
    "sub_test2_3" : 60,
  }
}
```

Here my jquery

```
$("#testing").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('/prices.json', function(jsonData) {
    alert(jsonData.test2.sub_test_2_2);
  });
});
```

The alert give me the right data : 50

So now, I define a simple variable like

```
var crazyVar = test2;
```

And I want to put this variable in the string "jsonData.test2.sub_test_2_2" like

```
$("#testing").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('/prices.json', function(jsonData) {
    alert(jsonData.crazyVar.sub_test_2_2);
  });
});
```

Of course, it fail :(

I read that I need to play with object, I tried all way to transform crazyVar in a sort of "Object" but impossible to find a just simple solution.

Comment: crazyVar is not assigned a value test2 will be null should it be jsonData.test2 ?

Comment: `jsonData.test2.sub_test_2_2 = crazyVar;` before alerting `alert(jsonData.test2.sub_test_2_2)`

Comment: Use `alert(jsonData[crazyVar].sub_test_2_2);`

Comment: The ```test2``` variable is ```undefined``` when you assign ```crazyVar```.
You want something like this:    

    jsonData.crazyVar = {};    
    jsonData.crazyVar.sub_test_2_2 = 70;

Comment: Assume `var crazyVar = "test2";`

Answer (score 5):

While accessing a object key using variable use `square []` brackets

```
var crazyVar = 'test2';
jsonData[crazyVar].sub_test_2_2
```

Comment: Work like a charm, but if I want to extend like

var crazyVar_1 = 'test2';
var crazyVar_2 = 'sub_test_2_2';

Can I use ? : 

jsonData[crazyVar_1].jsonData[crazyVar_2] (don't work actualy)